# Could not see privacy policy option in google play console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, privacy-policy

I created an app in google play console. I tried to upload apk and its throwing error as upload error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2W9l.png)

I could see option to enter privacy policy in google play console now. In store listing no options. Please let me know where I can enter privacy policy for my app in store listing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pwFy.png)

[image: Categorization]

[image: Contact details]

Answer (score 5):

[image: privacy policy google play 2020]

Apparently it has been moved to the "App content" section.

Answer (score 1):

It should be in the Store Listing tab:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I could not see. I could see only above attached screens in store listing.

Comment: @DevOndot What about Custom Store Listing?

Comment: Until app gets published, we could not edit Custom Store Listing. :(

Comment: It seems that it's an issue from Google Play --- https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/g7f60z/privacy_policy_field_not_visible_in_store_listing/

Answer (score 0):

They moved it. Now you can find it in the App content section

Answer (score 0):

see bottom-left corner: Policy / App content